# What's the difference between types of frequency filters?

Tags: analysis, filter

While trying to filter out low frequencies out of my recordings (in R, package Seewave and TuneR), I realized that there are many types of filters (butterworth filter, fir filter, square filter, etc.). Basic google-ing did not help me understand the difference between them and which filter would be the best, since I have very little knowledge in signal processing.

Does anyone have a good resource that explains the difference between filters and their application, accessible for biologists, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a long and complicated matter that ultimately involves reading several signal processing text books to fully embrace, but in short these different filter types relates to how steep they are, how many filter artefacts they generate and whether there is a time delay.
Stick to a butterworth filter and you will do fine in most cases:)

Comment: Welcome @Marinebioacoustics Aarhus Univ. Would you mind sharing one/few of the most accessible referred to. It'd make the answer more specific.